# Error implementing .switchMap in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire, switchmap

I'm am learning firebase to implement with my angular projects but running in to a issue with the .switchMap() operator.  My understanding is that it is supposed to get one observable and switch to another.  I am trying to get firebase user and switch to a authenticated application user.

**Error:**  AngularFireObject<{}> is not assignable to the parm of type (value: User, index: Number)

Here is my code

AuthGuard :

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.auth.user$
     .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid)) <-- error
     .map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin)
 }
```

UserService:

```
  get(uid:string){
   return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object()` method of the `AngularFireDatabase` service doesn't return an observable, it returns an `AngularFireObject`. This service allows you to data operations as well as create observable streams in different ways.

Instead use one of the observable stream methods provided like `valueChanges()`.

```
get(uid: string){
  return this.db.object('/users/' + uid).valueChanges();
}
```